# Environment variable not being found in Apache config

Tags: apache, docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

I have Apache web server running inside a docker container. It starts up correctly when the ServerName is set to dev.mysite.local. Like below...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.mysite.local

    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I change the ServerName to be ${MY_SERVER_NAME}

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ${MY_SERVER_NAME}

    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

and set the MY_SERVER_NAME as an environment variable in my docker-compose.yml file, I get the following error when starting apache:

> AH00111: Config variable ${MY_SERVER_NAME} is not defined.

I can shell into the container and run:

```
echo $MY_SERVER_NAME
```

which displays dev.mysite.local as expected, so the environment variable is present and set correctly.

My docker-compose.yml...

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: mysql_develop_db
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.5.58
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_secret_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - persist-data-volume:/var/lib/mysql
  app:
    container_name: my_app
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MY_SERVER_NAME=dev.mysite.local
volumes:
  persist-data-volume:
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Is this the correct way to make the Apache ServerName configurable through the docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Can you post your docker-compose.yml configurations here?

Comment: I have added the docker-compose.yml to the question.

Comment: i think this is what you're lookin for. .https://medium.com/@william.b/setting-dynamic-environmental-variables-in-apache-from-the-os-1d5c1e2e9e6c

Comment: Thank you. @FendiD That post has helped resolve my problem.